# How to do character math?

Tags: java, char

I'm not to sure how to use character math. In my program, i have a character array and i have to change the elements of the array, so that its the opposite of the character entered by the user. Example 'a' to 'z'. i guess i can change each element in the array, but that would take forever and would be a waste of time. So far i have tried nothing, i just don't know where to start.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SecretCodeMachine
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        SecretCodeMachine a = new SecretCodeMachine();

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        String input = in.nextLine();


        String print = a.encodeMessage(input);

        System.out.println(print);

    }
    public String encodeMessage(String pass)
    {

        char[] j = pass.toCharArray();
        String b = new String(j);
        return b;
    }
}
```

I have written the encodingMessage() method where all that code would be, im just not sure how i would approach this. Would i most likely use some type of loop?

Comment: Why would changing each element in the array be "a waste of time" and "take forever"? Just try it.

Comment: @merlin2011 y one would assume.

Comment: Well, from only knowing one example, A -> Z, I can only assume B -> Y

Comment: You can use a map `a->z, b->some_letter`, iterate over the array  input, and build the answer appending the value for each char.

Comment: Can you think of how to do this with integers (i.e. `a == 0`, `z == 25`)?  If so, you can use `int alphabetIndex = letterChar - 'a';` to work with integers as an intermediary if it's easier to think about.

Comment: Here's an example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html

Comment: It's going to look pretty strange for "au\0301" (á) to become "z\u0301" (ź). Perhaps you want to refine your algorithm and/or throw an exception for unexpected input.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a lookup table of valid input characters and what the output character should be.  This can be done with either a map or array, that is up to you. Then for each character, you would look it up in the table and place the output character into the new string.

But if you really need to use character math, which I can only assume meaning, converting the character to its corresponding ASCII int value, then doing some math to result in the correct int value of the resulting character. This will be much more complex, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can condition on whether it is in the first half of the alphabet or the second half, and do arithmetic with characters directly.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SecretCodeMachine
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        SecretCodeMachine a = new SecretCodeMachine();
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String input = in.nextLine();
        String print = a.encodeMessage(input);
        System.out.println(print);
    }
    public String encodeMessage(String pass)
    {
        char[] j = pass.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            // Lower case
            if (j[i] >= 'a' && j[i] <= 'z') {
                if (j[i] - 'a' <= 13) j[i] = (char) ('z' - (j[i] - 'a'));
                else j[i] = (char) ('a' + ('z' - j[i]));
            }
            // Upper Case
            else {
                if (j[i] - 'A' <= 13) j[i] = (char) ('Z' - (j[i] - 'A'));
                else j[i] = (char) ('A' + ('Z' - j[i]));
            }

        }
        String b = new String(j);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for all lowercase and [here is a link to the ASCII Table for your reference](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
for(int i = 0; i < j.length ; i ++){
            int f = j[i];
            int g = f - 97;
            int h = 25 - g * 2;
            j[i] += h;
        }
```